# Is this microserviced?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have created a simple blogging application using Spring Boot and RESTful APIs.  I have connected the same to a MySQL database to run some SQL queries like those for adding a blog, deleting a blog, etc.

My questions are as follows:

1. Does it mean that I have used a *microservice* architecture?  When does an architecture become a *microservice*? (I ask because many similar websites call an application as microservice-based.  Other than the main application, e.g., currency exchange instead of blogging, I see no other difference; for e.g., [this one](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-microservices-with-spring-boot-part-1-getting-started) - it does have many more aspects, but they are not contributing to its *microservice*-ness, IMHO).
2. Can I call an application as horizontally scalable if I am using *microservice-based* architecture?

Note:  The tutorial I followed is [here](https://medium.com/@salisuwy/building-a-spring-boot-rest-api-part-iii-integrating-mysql-database-and-jpa-81391404046a) and the GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/salisuwy/building-spring-boot-resp-api-v3).

Comment: Why downvote? Let me know if you need more info!  I am right here to update and answer any follow ups (if required at all).

Comment: You can begin by reading [microservice architecture](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html)

Comment: @AbelRoussi, thanks for the useful link.

Comment: Welcome ! I think you should describe what you've done in your Q ( at least the architecture of your project ) & also change the title of your Q

Comment: @AbelRoussi, I agree and I have described exactly that _to the best of my ability_.  This is but a small application, so I couldn't describe it more than what I already did.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: those aren't exact yes/no questions. I'll give you my opinion, but others will disagree.

You have created what most people would agree qualifies as a Microservice. But a Microservice does not make a Microservice architecture, in the same way that a tree doesn't make a forest.

A Microservice architecture is defined by creating a greater application that consists of several distributed components. What you have done is created a monolith (which is absolutely fine in most cases).

Almost every talk about Microservices that I have attended has featured this advice: start with a monolith, evolve to microservices once you need it.

Regarding the last question: your application is horizontally scalable if it is stateless. If you keep any session state, it can still be horizontally scalable, but you'll need a smart LB managing sticky sessions or distributed sessions. That's when things get interesting, and when you can start thinking about a Microservice architecture.

Common problems are: how can I still show my customers my website, if the order database, cart service, payment provider etc. are down. Service discovery, autoscaling, retry strategies, evolving Rest apis, those are common problems in a Microservice architecture. The more of them you use and need, the more you can claim to have a Microservice architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So, when you say evolve to microservices, you mean adding features, right?  Like using a nameserver, load balancing, etc.?

Comment: No, extracting functionality into separate, dedicated services. Breaking functionality out of a monolith. Plus the things you said.

Comment: What kinda of functionality could you please elaborate?  Like in this, I have followed OOP and have different functions that handle different stuff like creation, deletion, etc.

Comment: Again, you are not doing anything wrong, you are just not big enough to warrant a microservice architecture, and that is fine. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/MicroservicePrerequisites.html

Comment: I would not suggest introducing a Microservice architecture to a company that has less than about 50 developers, and it only really pays out fully for companies like Google, Netflix or Amazon.

Comment: Yes, I am just learning and doing all this out of pure interest.  Hence the questions. :)

Comment: "your application is horizontally scalable if it is stateless." - that is just wrong

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu no it isn't. it's incomplete. Stateless implies horizontally scalable, but it's not the only way to be horizontally scalable

Comment: If you disagree, how about providing your own answer?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd that statement is simply wrong (testable by simple logic) and also misleading. Except that, the answer is quite good.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yet you fail to provide that logic

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd you are in fact right, it is not wrong, just misleading: I read "only if"; if you start the sentence with the "if" then it is clearer.

Comment: There was never an "only", as I dislike absolute statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not at all. The use of microservices is an advanced architecture pattern that is hard to implement right, but that gives useful benefits in huge projects. This should not be of any concern to a small project, unless you want to test this particular architectural style.
2. Breaking an application in smaller chunk does increase its scalability, as resources can be increased on a smaller scale. However, statelesness, among other properties, are also key components to a scalable architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My query is similar to what I posted on another one - if I add features like load balancing, creating multiple instances, etc. then will it become a microservice?  (I want to create one since I am learning it).

Comment: You could separate identity management from blog management, thus creating two micro-services and run multiple processes of each independently (through a load balancer, kubernetes, docker swarm, etc). This would prove the principle.

Comment: Got you.  What do you mean by identity management and blog management, though?  Identity of _what_?

Comment: Well a blog usually has user accounts, user profiles and the likes. This is identity management. Blog management is whatever operation you do on your blog objects.

Comment: Okay, got you guys.  Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you showed us dont looks like microsservice at all.

You can say that you have an application that uses microsservices architecture when it is formed by microsservices(oh rly?) with independent functionalities and that can be scalable. Scale one service, means that you will run multiple instances (possible in multiple hosts) and it will be transparent for other services.

A good example to ilustrate that is a web store microsservice based composed by 4 microsservices:

- Sale Microsservice
- Product Microsservice
- Messaging Microsservice
- Authentication Microsservice

In a blackfriday event, for example, which theoretically will occur a lot of purchases, you can scale only the Sale Microsservice, saving resources from the other three (of course this means using a bunch of other technologies like proxy, LB ...). If you were using a monolithic architecture would need to scale all your application.

If you are using correctly a microsservice architecture, yes, you can say that your application is horizontally scalable.